# Parse and return URL in JSON

Tags: php, json

I have PHP code as follows:

```
$arr = array('url' => 'https://google.com/test');
echo json_encode($arr);
```

It's echoing:

```
{"url":"https:\/\/google.com\/test"}
```

How can I parse the URL correctly?

Comment: when you decode it, it will give you correct url back (it's just escaping `/`). so don't worry.:- https://eval.in/933927

Comment: What you have is correct, it's just escaping the `/`s.

Comment: This JSON output is being sent to the Android app. But I guess APP is not decoding it back.